# Select value in a SQL query based on count() being non-zero

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I am trying to write a SQL query that would "calculate" status column of the row based on `JOIN` with statuses table.

My record is basically: `id | name | statusId`, which is foreign key to statuses table. That table has: `id | statusName`

I collect `count()` for each `DISTINCT` statusId. Now, I need return Id of any status based on the following idea - `if count(status0) > 0`, I need to return `status0`, else I need to check `status1` then `status2` etc.

Could I write a SQL query to return status for each row status with `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `HAVING` etc without if/else logic?

Comment: hint: use HAVING

Comment: Where are the columns Status0, Status1, etc.?  Your table structure is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the statuses that are being used, then use `exists`:

```
select s.*
from statuses s
where exists (select 1 from records r where r.statusid = s.id);
```

Actually, if you just want the ids, you can use:

```
select distinct r.statusid
from records;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing the question, do you want to just get the statuses that are present in the bigger table? How about?

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM status s
 WHERE s.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT statusid FROM records);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with this it should get you on the right track...

```
select a.*, b.*, c.cnt from table1 a
join table2 b on a.statusid=b.id
join (
select statusname, count(*) cnt
from table1 a join table2 b on a.statusid=b.id
group by statusname)c
on b.statusname=c.statusname
```